# MultiValueDictKeyError when trying to change profile image

Tags: python, django

[views.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KA7U4.png)
every thing working okay just image cant be changed and i dont why so, i think there is some fuction or some thing like request.POST[image] to get an image

[template.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GN58b.png)

Comment: Welcome to the community. Please follow this link to ask better questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use "request.FILES" instead of "request.POST" to access files.
For more info use this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/file-uploads/)